# Hamlpy and Inclusion tag messing up divs

Tags: django, django-templates, haml

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I have a hamlpy template that calls an inclusion tag that renders another template.

Both the parent template and the included one are indented properly. However, after the inclusion tag, the rest of the html is rendered as if it was in the same div as the inclusion tag.

I tried adding to the indent in the included template, and the parent template but that didn't help.

Parent Haml

```
 .main-column
    .column-holder
        .title
         ...
    - for promotion in live_promotions
      - display_promotion promotion
 .main-column
    .column-holder
      .title
        ...
  - for promotion in completed_promotions
    - display_promotion promotion
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this only an indentation problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an indentation issue in one of the parent templates. Thanks for trying to help!